# wamp64 error 403 access forbidden from another computer

Tags: apache, web, wamp, settings

i trying to reach my webpages out from may local network. but i got error message "forbidden You don't have permission to access /test/ on this server.
Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at 192.168.1.139 Port 3388"

my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

what can i do, i am desperate :(
thanks for the help

Comment: Can you ping this computer from antoher?

Answer (score -1):

Comment line:

```
# Require local
```

That's work for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it really helps other users find good answers if you explain why your answer solves the original question.  Can you edit your answer to include more details about the solution you came up with.